# Android Image processing edge correction

Tags: android, image, android-studio, colors

I am using an android phone to to take a **640x480** resolution picture of a sheet of paper with a white background and colored figures on it. I am having the following problem:
[image: Original zoomed picture without values]

And here I have entered the **RGB** values of certain pixels that describe my problem:
[image: Zoomed picture with values added]

On the second picture I have added the **RGB** values of certain pixels. By design(the picture was drawn in a PDF before printing) there is no border/edge/margin between the magenta color and the white background. But in the pictures I get the described border/edge/margin between the **background** and the **magenta** color.

My question is the following: What is the cause of this effect and what is its name? How can I prevent this effect from appearing in my pictures and to achieve the effect of smooth transition between two colors? I have used Lenovo Vibe P1(m), HTC, Samsung Core duos, Samsung S4 and all of them show this effect in the pictures. The problem is worse because I must differ from two different colors in my pictures, and when this effect appears in printed NUMBERS that have a **magenta** color, they become more or less gray or black and I need them to be a color close to **magenta**.

Comment: I believe this is an artifact created due to compression. Is this a JPEG?

Comment: Actually it is a JPG. But the problem isn't in the JPG format, becuause before saving this picture, I am making analysis on a `YUV` image with `YuvImage` class in Android Studio. And when looking at the pixels of the YUV image I get the same effect of a border.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry! I am using JPG in my program as well. I do not do analysis on YUV image.

Answer (score 0):

Some of that may be JPEG compression, but mostly it's the optic chip output being noisy a bit, and aliasing. At 640x480 the noise will be quite low, as most of it is aliased with such low resolution. But the aliasing itself will be worse.

What I mean by aliasing:

Let's imagine the figure on paper is printed as (in fine resolution):

```
***_____   ("*" being magenta, "_" being white paper)
****____
******__
*****___
****____
**______
```

And this part of paper fits into single pixel of 640x480 photo.

What should be it's colour? Half of the area is white, half is magenta, so it will be roughly about "(magenta + white) / 2" colour, but that's not exactly how colours and brightness optically mix, so the hue of final "aliased" pixel may be more toward grey colour than you expect.

You should design your paper patterns in such way, that you can always reasonably detect some larger magenta area, and nearby edges (print vs white), then the nearby edges mark as magenta by that area detected, even if the pixels at the edge itself looks more like grey colour.

When you have two colours and only texts in font, use BOLD fonts, and higher camera resolution, and some heuristic to accumulate colour info over small area and maybe even over several captured images (time)... But fonts will be numerically very close to grey. Actually when you print a grey text on paper, and start to capture it with mobile phone camera, it will have some pixels quite in colour, magenta and green being favourite one (noise in input data + compression artefacts).

Also try different colours, magenta is sort of unlucky pick, as it comprises mostly of red and blue, while usually the most sensitive HW channel is green - as human's eye is most sensitive to green light, when the HW design starts to hit some limits and they need to lower down sensitivity on some channel, the first pick is blue (least sensitive for human eye), then red, and the most fidelity is kept for green. Shouldn't be much of problem with high quality capture device, but with lower/medium quality HW and JPEG compression the green based colour will get some advantage.

---

Plus I completely forgot to mention the sharpness of image. It takes quite some luck to receive perfectly focused and static (in terms of movement) image from capture device. When processing a video stream, most of the images will be blurred both by the movement/shaking of device, and also by the non-ideal focus of optics. That will make sharp print edges blurry on the image, and the blur will again suffer from colour-hue loss lot more, than simple Math ((magenta+white)/2) numbers.

And light conditions... Many computer-vision/OCR experiments done in summer will surprise you, when you will try to repeat those tests in winter...

Comment: I am sorry but what do you mean by HW in "HW channel"? And are you saying that If the color wasn't magenta, but was green, it wouldn't have such effect? What if I add a custom border of width 1-2 pixels which has the value (red+white)/2? Would that remove the down-up-down effect of the border? Thanks

Comment: @ZdravkoDonev well, the picture taken by phone is not drawn by little dwarf inside the phone, but some variation on [CCD chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-coupled_device) is used to collect the light data. It's piece of HW. It's very rarely done as evenly distributed RGB sensors, as for many reasons (I didn't care to study, human eye is just one of them) the HW guys prefer all kinds of "weird" configurations, for example 2x2 pixel matrix with 2 green and 1 red + 1 blue filters (to get more accurate readings of green), or even more "exotic" (for "RGB" SW guy like me) like YUV, etc.

Comment: @ZdravkoDonev you will have such effect even with green color, just the sensor readings will be a bit more accurate than magenta, because the part of effect coming from noise will be lower with green. Part of effect done by aliasing will remain almost identical. I don't think you can add "1-2 pixels" on paper. You can certainly add 1-2 pixel tolerance to your image processing algorithm. Or if your aim is not to track image correctly, but actually to provide good photo quality, you may consider taking picture in 2-4*higher resolution, and downscale with high quality filter algorithm.

Comment: @ZdravkoDonev finally.. just set your camera to highest possible resolution/sensitivity and store the raw data (raw-est possible, "true raw" is rarely accessible on android phone, only jpeg damaged or some Yuv direct surface buffer in a bit lower resolution). And check them pixel by pixel to see how much "noise" the photo contains, even if you shoot well lit solid colour object without any edges or gradients.

Comment: Yes, about the raw data - At first I tried to analyze my image as and YUV format, but there were different algorithms for getting RGB value from an YUV "pixel" and if I found same algorithm on different sites, they would be with different multiplying constants. And when I saved the image(in JPG) I got different images(which confuses the process of checking my algorithms).

Comment: Settings the phones camera to 640x480 was a decision for reducing the noise in the image(which actually works as far as I saw in my test images). And working with 640x480 is of course faster than bigger resolution images. My task is actually to check if there is a blue or black ink over the magenta or the white of the paper. And when the magenta is changing to gray/black it is a harder task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127189/discussion-between-zdravko-donev-and-ped7g).